# How to exclude an entity field when doing an update with JPA

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Is there a way to make a field non-persistent at update operation but persistent at create operation with JPA - Hibernate 4?

I tried it in this way

```
@Transient
@Id
@Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false, length = 75)
private String userName;
```

but with @Transient annotation the field will be transient across all CRUD operations and I want a way to specify that only on this operation is persistent (create).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `@Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false, length = 75, updatable=false)`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to set `updatable` attribute of the `@Column` annotation to `false`:

```
@Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false, length = 75, updatable= false)
private String userName;
```

The `updatable` attribute instruct Hibernate to omit this column from the generated `UPDATE` SQL statement.

I removed the `@Transient` and the `@Id` annotations.

If this column is your PK (mapped to the entity identifier), then you can only set it during INSERT, since Hibernate doesn't allow you to update an entity identifier (the `updatable` attribute being redundant in this case).

Comment: What's the use of length attribute here?

Comment: @muasif80 if you're also using JPA to generate the DDL.