# JPA findAll order by a linked list size

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am facing a problem and I have no idea if is possible to do it using JPA.

I am trying to make a query using JPA and make the following:

Get all courses with the course entity fields (id, name) but also with a non persistent field (@Transient) that will be filled with the count of all students related with this course

Something like this:

```
List<Course> courses = courseRepository.findAll();
```

but instead get (representing as json for example purposes)

```
[{1, soccer}, {2, art}, {3, singing}]
```

I need something like this

```
[{1, soccer, 2}, {2, art, 0}, {3, singing, 1}]
```

As you can see the values 2, 0 a 1 is the **count** of the table students of all the related rows

```
Student table
| id | name | description | course |
|  1 | thg1 | a thing     | 1      |
|  2 | thg2 | another one | 1      |
|  3 | thg3 | one more    | 3      |   

Course Table
| id | name | 
|  1 | soccer |     
|  2 | art |     
|  3 | singing |
```

So, the restriction is that one student can attend one course ONLY.

Using JPA I want to select all the courses but due I am using pagination there is no way I can do it on the spring part (I mean as a service), I am trying to do it directly with JPA, is there any way I can achieve this? Maybe with specification? Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: write a method in your interface with `@Query` with the query like `select s.course, c.name, count (s.course) from Student  s left join Course c where s.course=c.id Group By s.course`

Comment: Why don't you use mapping?

Comment: any idea how to do it with mapping @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn ?

Comment: I wonder if `@JsonIgnore` might be useful here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) to achieve what you need.

Assuming that you are using the following entities:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Course implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @Transient
    private Long total;

    public Course() {
    }

    public Course(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Course course;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name, Course course) {
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
    }
}
```

1) Then you can create the [interface based projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces)

```java
public interface CourseWithCountProjection {
    Integer getId();
    String getName();
    Long getTotal();
}
```

and the following query method in the Course repository:

```java
public interface CourseRepo extends JpaRepository<Course, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "" +
            "select " +
            "  c.id as id, " +
            "  c.name as name, " +
            "  count(s) as total " +
            "from " +
            "  Course c " +
            "  left join Student s on s.course.id = c.id " +
            "group by " +
            "  c " +
            "order by " +
            "  count(s) desc" +
            "", countQuery = "select count(c) from Course c")
    Page<CourseWithCountProjection> getProjectionWithCount(Pageable pageable);    
}
```

In this case you don't need the transient `total` field in the `Course` and you can **remove it**.

Note that you have to add the extra `countQuery` parameter to the `@Query` annotation because the main query has the grouping.

Also pay attention on aliases in the query (`c.id as id` etc) - they are necessary when you are using projections.

2) Another way is to use the the `Course` constructor in the JPQL query as @KarolDowbecki has already shown. You can use it with almost the same query:

```java
public interface CourseRepo extends JpaRepository<Course, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "" +
        "select " +
        "  new Course(c.id, c.name, count(s)) " +
        "from " +
        "  Course c " +
        "  left join Student s on s.course.id = c.id " +
        "group by " +
        "  c " +
        "order by " +
        "  count(s) desc" +
        "", countQuery = "select count(c) from Course c")
    Page<Course> getCoursesWithCount(Pageable pageable);
}
```

**UPDATED**

The first option is more preferable, because it divides the **model** (`Course`) and the **view** (`CourseWithCountProjection`) from each other.

**UPDATED 2**

To get dynamic sorting you can exclude `order by` from the query and provide sorting in the `Pageable` parameter of the query method, for example:

```
@Query(value = "" +
        "select " +
        "  c.id as id, " +
        "  c.name as name, " +
        "  count(s) as total " +
        "from " +
        "  Course c " +
        "  left join Student s on s.course.id = c.id " +
        "group by " +
        "  c " +
        "", countQuery = "select count(c) from Course c")
Page<CourseWithCountProjection> getProjectionWithCount(Pageable pageable);

Page<CourseWithCountProjection> result = parentRepo.getProjectionWithCount(PageRequest.of(0, 20, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "total")));
```

Working example is here: [sb-jpa-orderby-related](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-jpa-orderby-related)

Comment: shouldnt the @Transient be part of student?

Comment: is "title" the name of the db field?  the name of the course

Comment: @jpganz18 "@Transient in student" what do you mean? "title" is my misprint ) It's `total` - the alias for `count(s)` - the total number of students in groups (I've updated my answer). Aliases in SQL sentences must correspond to their getters in projections.

Comment: Is there anyway I can make the @Query without the OrderBy and let it for JPA? like getCourseWIthCountOrderByTotal?

Comment: @jpganz18 if you mean the dynamic sorting, then - yes, it's possible. See my updated answer.

Comment: isnt this sorting valid only for that specific page ONLY ?

Comment: @jpganz18 what do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `@Formula` annotation from Hibernate:

```
@Formula("select count(*) FROM student s WHERE s.course = id")
private int totalStudents;
```

> Sometimes, you want the Database to do some computation for you rather
>   than in the JVM, you might also create some kind of virtual column.
>   You can use a SQL fragment (aka formula) instead of mapping a property
>   into a column. This kind of property is read only (its value is
>   calculated by your formula fragment).
>
> ```
> @Formula("obj_length * obj_height * obj_width")
> public long getObjectVolume()
> ```
>
> The SQL fragment can be as complex as you want and even include
>   subselects.

[hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-property)

Alternative you can use a bidirectional relation to count the students:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="course")
private List<Student> students;

public int getTotalStudents() {
    return students.size();
}
```

Or with a `transient` field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="course")
private List<Student> students;

@Transient
private int studentCount;

@PostLoad
public void setStudentCount() {
    studentCount = students.size();
}
```

To avoid the N+1 issue that was mentioned by Cepr0 you can set the fetch mode to join:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="course")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private List<Student> students;
```

Comment: The question is about JPA not Hibernate (JPAVendor). I think the OP was meant to be solvable in plain JPA-style.

Comment: @Cepr0 Thanks I was not aware of this.

Comment: @MWiesner Spring Data Jpa uses Hibernate as default vendor so it can be relevant for the OP

Comment: @Tom This is be correct. Yet, you might want to switch/exchange this default with another jpa vendor/provider. Once you compile against `@Formula` you will loose portability of your code base. That was my point.

Comment: Hi,  is it possible to have an orderBy over that computed field? and where should I use my @Formula? on my entity?

Comment: The second option is also not optimal since it leads to loading of redundant data (all students for all courses). Imagine that there are thousands of them! And even If you try to split it into pages the Hibernate does this in the memory because of joining data (

Comment: @jpganz18 You can use oderBy with the Formula ore even more complex queries. Yes, use Formula on a entity field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom `GROUP BY` query that will create a projection:

```
@Query("SELECT new full.path.to.Course(c.id, c.name, count(s)) " +
       "FROM Course c " +
       "LEFT JOIN Student s " +
       "GROUP BY c.id")
List<Course> findCourseWithStudentCount();
```

Assuming that you have the corresponding constructor in the `Course` class this will return projection objects. They won't be managed as entitites but if you don't plan to modify them later they will do.

Comment: is there a way to do it without jpql?

Comment: @jpganz18 You could try Hibernate `@Formula` annotation or create a new DB view that will provide this one column and then read it. Both solutions are not as portable as JPA query.

Comment: is there any alternative using specifications?

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a new view in your DB, which collects all the information you need (e.g. using a group-by statement). The view should then contain data like this, in exactly the form you need it later:

```
CourseWithStudents view
| id | course  | students
|  1 | soccer  | 2
|  2 | art     | 0
|  3 | singing | 1
```

Creating a new class (maybe extending your current `Course` class) could be mapped to this view:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CourseWithStudents")
class CourseWithStudents extends Course {
    // Insert Mapping
}
```

You can then select all the information from the new view:

```
List<CourseWithStudents> courses = courseStudentRepository.findAll();
```

But since you can't update a view, this solution only works if all you need is read-access. If you want to change your Course/Student object and update it in the DB after this selection, this approach does not work.

Comment: could you specify more how to reach to this solution? findAll will not bring the amount of students by default...

Comment: If you use a new entity mapped to the new view containing the student count, a findAll for that new entity will contain the requested information. I have extended my answer to include a bit more details.

Answer (score 0):

Marking a field as @Transient tells JPA that the field is not persisted. As a result, JPA will not map data to the field.

Are you just wanting the field to not be updateable?  Maybe you can remove the @Transient annotation and set 'updateable' property on the field to false?

[How to exclude an entity field when doing an update with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363625/how-to-exclude-an-entity-field-when-doing-an-update-with-jpa)

Comment: Without persisting that field and no using the @transient, is there anyway to achieve what I am asking for?